# add a response header to tell a browser to use a specific launch application

Tags: ipad, safari, http-headers, mime-types, content-disposition

I want to tell a browser to in a header of the server response, to launch a specific application to open a specific file.
In particular if I want to view a pdf file (which is present on my server) on my browser, in safari (iPad), using iBooks, how do I do it?
I specify the mime-type of the requested (http request) file (in this case application/pdf)  and the content disposition in the response header, but when the pdf file opens, I can view only the first page, I don't get an option to scroll down to view other pages in the pdf file. I have this issue on the browser Safari (iPad). I'm writing the server side code, processing the http request.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot possibly instruct the device to use a specific application for your file.